# Native Java library for the amCharts

Tags: android, amcharts

I would like to work with amCharts (World Map) in Android. I need help regarding native library. World map will be responsive.

As amChart based on JavaScript, I am getting solution with JavaScript, in case of Google Region Geo Chart.

Answer (score 2):

This is not AMChart. But this library will help you achieve whatever graphs you need similar to AMChart.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/40

If you want alternatives,you can go through 2nd link

Comment: MPAndroidChart not provide world Map Chart (Region wise)